# How to remove spaces between multiple tables, and still let it spill into multiple pages?

Tags: tables, formatting, captions, layout

I've seen many questions regarding 2 tables, but for some reason none of the solutions worked for me when I have multiple tables, which may extend to a new page.

The example below is for 2 tables, but in my actual document I have many tables, and there is a large space between them.  I tried the following:

1. Rolling them all into a single table using `\begin{table}`...`\end{table}`.  This does indeed remove the whitespace.  But the problem is that when there are many tables over multiple pages, then it doesn't break into a new page in the correct place.  It just truncates the table and the rest of the table disappears.

2. However, when I split them up, as shown below, then there is a large whitespace in between.
3. Of course I can manually insert `\begin{table}`....`\end{table}` for a subset of the tables (perhaps the first 2 or 3), and then let the page break happen, and then group the remaining tables `\begin{table}`....`\end{table}`, but that doesn't seem like a sustainable solution to me because as the document changes I would have to update this.

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{table}[] 
\caption{S } 
\label{tab:mytable} 
\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}} 
\toprule 
  & a  & b & q \\ \midrule 
0 & 5  & 2 & 9.0    \\ 
0 & 5 & 5 & .39     \\ 
0 & 5 & 3 & .73     \\ \bottomrule 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table} 
\setlength{\floatsep}{0.1pt} 
\begin{table}[] 
\caption{S } 
\label{tab:mytable} 
\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}} 
\toprule 
  & a  & b & q \\ \midrule 
0 & 5  & 2 & 9.0    \\ 
0 & 5 & 5 & .39     \\ 
0 & 5 & 3 & .73     \\ \bottomrule 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

How do I reduce the space between multiple tables, yet still allow the page breaks to happen naturally?

Comment: you can put both tabular and both captions in the same table if you want them to stay together, but don't do `\begin{table}[] ` that means the table is allowed nowhere: latex will warn about that and remove the option

Comment: if you want to set floatsep set it in the preamble (or at least on the page before the tables appear) not between the tables.

Comment: I tried `\setlength{\floatsep}{0.1pt}` in the preamble, but that did not change anything for me.

Comment: You have not provided a test document that allows debugging `table`  is not defined by default, it is defined by the documentclass which you have not shown

Comment: Just added it:  `\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}`

Comment: I editted the question and I ask that it be re-considered for opening.  I didn't realize this issue was not resolved by the solutions to the 2-table problems.

Answer (score 2):

You used `\begin{table}[]` which means do not allow the float anywhere.

LaTeX assumes you did not mean that and warns:

```
LaTeX Warning: No positions in optional float specifier.
               Default added (so using `htbp') on input line 8.
```

as it happens it ended up using `h` so the effective parameter is not `\floatsep` but `\intextsep`

[image]

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\setlength{\intextsep}{-10.1pt}
\raggedbottom
\begin{document} 
\begin{table}[] 
\caption{S } 
\label{tab:mytable} 
\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}} 
\toprule 
  & a  & b & q \\ \midrule 
0 & 5  & 2 & 9.0    \\ 
0 & 5 & 5 & .39     \\ 
0 & 5 & 3 & .73     \\ \bottomrule 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table} 

\begin{table}[] 
\caption{S } 
\label{tab:mytable} 
\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}} 
\toprule 
  & a  & b & q \\ \midrule 
0 & 5  & 2 & 9.0    \\ 
0 & 5 & 5 & .39     \\ 
0 & 5 & 3 & .73     \\ \bottomrule 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Note `h` would not have been defaulted by the standard classes, this is specific to `llncs` (which you had not mentioned in the original version of the question)

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful.  Unfortunately someone closed my question, claiming it was a duplicate, so I modified it to be more clear.  Hope it's okay.

Comment: sure I reopened the question so I could post an answer @somewhere

Comment: I added `\setlength{\intextsep}{-10.1pt}
\raggedbottom`. But this still suffers from the problem I alluded to:  When the table extends beyond the page, it just gets truncated and doesn't start a new page.  I'm trying to avoid setting `\begin{table}`...`\end{table}` manually.  Do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: Also, do you mind helping me understand what do you mean by "which means do not allow the float anywhere. ?

Comment: @somewhere `[tbp]` means allow floats top bottom or on a float page, `[th]` means allow floats top or here `[h]` means allow just here (this usually gets changed to `[ht]`)  so `[]` means don't allow floats anywhere.  An argument of `[]` is not the same as not having the optional argument at all: use `\begin{table}` not `\begin{table}[]`  just as `\\ ` is not the same as `\\[]` (which gives an error)

Comment: dont set the space negative" thatt was just exageration to show the effect. I stuck `-10` in fromt of your `.1pt` example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150279/discussion-between-somewhere-and-david-carlisle).